# Problems with displaying strings in layouts

Tags: page-layout, string, user-interface

[image]I added a section to a standard layout in which I entered several fields. I have a string field in which spaces can not be inserted and the value can be very long (255 characters) the layout brings out the scrollbar causing problems of visualization of a custom visualforce contained in the layout. Is it possible to set a size to display the text on several lines?

Comment: Is it classic or lightning?

Comment: classic, sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Per this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187551&type=1), there's no way to wrap a text field's value with no spaces.

Comment: You can do something different to fix this. Create a forumla field to truncate the text, if that helps. TRIM(Left(Website,100))